# Tacx Flow Smart trainer calibration issues with 700x35c tyre

Tags: tire, training, turbo-trainer, indoor, tyre-width

I'm getting into cycling properly and I have bought myself the **[Tacx Flow](https://tacx.com/product/flow-smart/)** smart trainer along with an adventure/gravel bike. I chose adventure/gravel over a road bike as I can see myself wanting to ride light to medium woodland trails around places like Ladybower Reservoir.

I have set the trainer up and I have mounted my bike onto it as per the instructions/downloaded the app etc.

After connecting to my phone and clicking on the 'calibrate' function, I cycle up to the designated 30kph and stop pedalling as instructed only to be greeted with an error message.

> There was an error during calibration. Please try again.

[image]

I have attempted this numerous times, each time making adjustments such as pumping the tyres up to their max rated pressure of **6.5 bar / 95 psi**, and increasing the tension between trainer and tyre, however I still receive the error message that calibration has failed.

Does anybody know of anything that may be causing an issue?

Just for clarity, my tyres are **700x35c**
I have also made sure the **Tacx Utility app** I am using is up to date.

[image]

**Note:** I have been receiving the error message on both my iPad 3 (a little old, I know), but also my OnePlus 3T Android phone.

Update:
I have since read a few more questions on the internet regarding people with similar issues, and I have attempted their solutions.

1. I released the back brake entirely to ensure that there was no extra friction slowing the wheel on deceleration
2. I followed Tacx's guide to set up to the letter, stating that I should find the point where, when levered down, the flywheel should only just touch the tyre, and then tighten up by 4 rotations

All of this still yielded an error...

**PS. This is my tyre on it at the moment while I wait for my trainer**
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I actually had a momentary breakthrough!

After tinkering with the Tacx Windows 10 software, I set up my own test workout (10 mins flat, nothing special). After wimping out after 7 mins (I need to get fit, IKR!) I remembered that somebody had the advice of warming the tyres up before calibrating. This makes sense.

So I hopped back on the bike and tried the Utility app for Android and **BOOM** I got a readout right at the top end of green informing me that I need to slacken it off a little. Success, right?

I then tried again after slackening the tension by 1 turn and it appears to be back to the same old error fun I was having previously... Technology, who would have it?

Comment: What error message?

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Updated questino - The error was `There was an error during calibration. Please try again.`

Comment: Well, gee, that's so very useful.  :-/  Some product engineers and testers are apparently overpaid and can't be bothered to write useful error messages...

Comment: Any correlation with what you're doing when you get that non-informative message?  Hitting a certain speed? Maybe hearing/feeling the tire start to slip?

Comment: What do your tires look like?  I wonder if the tires are heavily lugged and this is upsetting the contact between tire and the devices wheel thing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - With regards to when this is happening... I click on the calibrate button, it tells me to spin up to 30km/h and then stop and it counts my speed as I do this. It is when I have stopped peddling once reached 30 and informed to do so that the flywheel decelerates and upon stopping, I then get the error message spat out at me. This is happening both on Android and iOS.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - I have the tyres that were on at the time of purchase (2nd or 3rd hand at this point) as I am waiting for my 700x35 training tyre to arrive. I have had no such slipping, or at least I haven't hear or felt any thus far.

Comment: I wonder if you have excessive drag for some reason, causing the tire to slow too rapidly.  Or possibly the pickup cylinder is not making good contact in the first place.

Comment: @DanielRHicks That may be the case. The tyres look ok to me, worn but OK (See updated photo of tyre in question).

Comment: I don't see the photo.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I replied before posting the photo XD
Also... See my update about the app actually giving me a result for once!

Comment: The TACX trainers are notorious for calibration problems. See at DC Rainmaker's website. It has a longish article. Not only needs the tyre be warmed up but the device also. Apparently you should ride for 20min before attempting calibration. It will work, eventually. Don't get discouraged!

Comment: @Carel - I don't think my legs will last that long at this stage! Haha. I don't think it helps that I killed my legs with an impromptu run yesterday without a warmup XD. I will give it another go and update :-)

Comment: @Carel - Fantastic news! You were correct in saying that I should have done a warm up for 20 mins. I tested just normal riding for 10 mins an attempted but no luck, and then rode another 10 mins and finally got some proper results!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After listening to advice from @Carel, I warmed the tyres up for 20 minutes, a lot more than I would have envisaged, and I finally got consistent results being able to calibrate more than once.

After a bit of slackening, I managed to calibrate to the centre of the green zone. I can't wait to re-do the whole process after my training tyre arrives!

A quick thank you to @AndrewHenle and @DanielRHicks for their time and help also :-)

Comment: Use of a hairdryer to get some heat into the tire ma help in future.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I was joking earlier that I could put my tyre (folded up of course) in the oven for a spell, or invest in tyre warmers XD.